# Finding a system of homogeneous linear equations given solution space

Tags: homogeneous-equation

If, in $R^4$, $\alpha_1 = (-1,0,1,2)$, $\alpha_2 = (3,4,-2,5)$, $\alpha_1 = (1,4,0,9)$, is given,
How can I find a system of homogeneous linear equations with solutions space which is exactly spanned by above three vectors?

I don't know even how to start with it. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Try using the definitions of "Span" and "Homogeneous system", do you remember/know these?

Comment: Yes, I keep thinking that, if I find such an system,(say matrix A), Av = 0 where v is linear combination of three vectors above. However, after that, all I can think is setting unknown quantities and using inner product, which is not on the material in the chapter.

Answer (score -1):

We want $a,b,c,d$ such that 
\begin{align}
-a+c+2d=0\\
3a+4b-2c+5d=0\\
a+4b+9c=0
\end{align}

Row-reducing we get 
\begin{align}
a-c-2d=0\\
b+\frac{1}{4}c+\frac{11}{4}d=0
\end{align}

Hence our solution set is $\{(c+2d,-\frac{1}{4}c-\frac{11}{4}d,c,d):c,d\in \mathbb{R}\}$

Thus if we consider the system
\begin{align}
4x_1-x_2+4x_3=0\\
8x_1-11x_2+4x_4=0
\end{align}

we would get a solution spanned by the given vectors.

Comment: There should be $d$ in place of $c$ in third equation.